# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using jQuery UI to render an ASP.NET MVC 5 partial view into an empty div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".SiteName").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var siteName = $(this).data("sitename");
        //alert(siteName);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/EtlLog/ListSiteJobs?SiteDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(siteName),
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (result) {
            $("#ListSite").html(result).dialog("open");
        });
    });
})
```

Inspecting the ListSite div after the click, I see that it is filled with the expected results but I get a jQuery UI error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

I've tried various combinations of .ready() and even nesting the div being rendered within a div used for .dialog(). Must have looked at every question about this error, but still not finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to 'setup' the dialog, then `open` it. try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".SiteName").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var siteName = $(this).data("sitename");
        //alert(siteName);
        $("#ListSite")
           .load("/EtlLog/ListSiteJobs?SiteDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(siteName))
           .dialog({autoOpen:true})
    });
})
```

**P.S:** I took the liberty to shorten your code using `load()`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! But why is the dialog transparent? I was expecting the default...

Comment: There are no clues as to why it would be transparent in your current code examples, as none of them have to do with styling. Go through the standard steps. Make sure you included the jquery ui css file. Make sure your control doesn't have invalid html or whacked inline css rules. Make sure other example ui dialogs are working in your site, etc.